# How to formally prove that $f(x,y)= - \frac{x^2}{y}$ is continuous on the points where $y \neq 0$?

Tags: analysis, limits, continuity

How to formally prove that $f(x,y)= - \frac{x^2}{y}$ is continuous on the points where $y \neq 0$? I know this is obvious, but I'm stuck on how to write a formally proof.

Comment: If you want to use the analytical definition, I'd start with $y\neq0$ implies $|y|\geq\delta_1>0$. Now you can apply the definition of continuity and just find a $\delta$-ball appropriately small.

Comment: Well, $f$ ist the quotient of two continuos functions.

Answer (score 1):

Let $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)$ be pairs so that $y_1,y_2\neq 0$, and let $\Delta x=x_2-x_1,\Delta y=y_2-y_1$.

$$\begin{align}\Delta f=f(x_2,y_2)-f(x_1,y_1)&=\frac{x_1^2y_2-x_2^2y_1}{y_1y_2}\\
&=\frac{x_1^2(y_1+\Delta y) - (x_1+\Delta x)^2y_1}{y_1y_2}\\
&=\frac{x_1^2\Delta y-2x_1y_1\Delta x - y_1(\Delta x)^2}{y_1(y_1+\Delta y)}
\end{align}$$

To make $|\Delta f|$ small, first, ensure that $|\Delta y|< \frac{|y_1|}{2}$ so that $|y_1(y_1+\Delta y)|>\frac{|y_1|^2}{2}$. We also need $|\Delta x|< 1$ so that $|\Delta x|^2<|\Delta x|$.

So we have,under these assumptions for $\Delta x,\Delta y$, that:

$$\begin{align}\Delta f &= \frac{1}{|y_1||y_1+\Delta y|} \left|x_1^2 \Delta y- 2x_1y_1 \Delta x - y_1(\Delta x)^2\right|\\
&\leq \frac{2}{|y_1|^2} \max(|\Delta x|,|\Delta y|)\left( |x_1|^2+2|x_1y_1|+|y_1|\right)
\end{align}$$

So, given $\epsilon>0$, choose $$\delta = \min\left(1,\frac{|y_1|}{2},\frac{|y_1|^2\epsilon}{2\left(|x_1|^2+2|x_1y_1|+|y_1|\right)}\right)$$

Work backwards then and show that if $\sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2}< \delta$ then $\max(|\Delta x|,|\Delta y|)<\delta$, and then show $|\Delta f|<\epsilon$.